# error in calculating rowsum of column having NA values

Tags: r

while calculating rowsum if both the column have values but getting error
what i am doing wrong

```
df <- data.frame("T_1_1"= c(68,NA,0,105,NA,0,135,NA,24),
                 "T_1_2"=c(26,NA,0,73,NA,97,46,NA,0),
                 "T_1_3"=c(93,32,NA,103,NA,0,147,NA,139),
                 "S_2_1"=c(69,67,94,0,NA,136,NA,92,73),
                 "S_2_2"=c(87,67,NA,120,NA,122,0,NA,79),
                 "S_2_3"= c(150,0,NA,121,NA,78,109,NA,0),
                 "T_1_0"= c(79,0,0,NA,98,NA,15,NA,2)
                 
                 
)
df <- df %>% mutate(x1 = ifelse(is.na(T_1_1) & is.na(S_2_1),NA,rowSums(c(T_1_1,S_2_1),na.rm = TRUE)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `x1`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
i Input `x1` is `ifelse(...)`.
```

output should be like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select specific columns use `rowSums` in `select` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(x1 = ifelse(is.na(T_1_1) & is.na(S_2_1),NA,
                       rowSums(select(., c(T_1_1,S_2_1)),na.rm = TRUE)))

#  T_1_1 T_1_2 T_1_3 S_2_1 S_2_2 S_2_3 T_1_0  x1
#1    68    26    93    69    87   150    79 137
#2    NA    NA    32    67    67     0     0  67
#3     0     0    NA    94    NA    NA     0  94
#4   105    73   103     0   120   121    NA 105
#5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    98  NA
#6     0    97     0   136   122    78    NA 136
#7   135    46   147    NA     0   109    15 135
#8    NA    NA    NA    92    NA    NA    NA  92
#9    24     0   139    73    79     0     2  97
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that rowSums does not work with vectors, the input needs to be a data frame. So convert the concatenated vectors to a data frame first:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(
    is.na(df$T_1_1) & is.na(df$S_2_1),
    NA,
    rowSums(data.frame(c(df$T_1_1,df$S_2_1)),
            na.rm = TRUE
            )
    )
    )
```

Comment: no giving the required output, just updated question